# Delete pointers in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

Is this a right way of deleting pointers in a vector? Is it ok to use indices instead of itertors?

```
    std::vector<int*> stuff;
    int *a = new int(10);
    int *b = new int(20); 
    int *c = new int(30);

    stuff.push_back(a);
    stuff.push_back(b);
    stuff.push_back(c);

    for (int i = 0; i < stuff.size(); i++ ){
        delete (stuff[i]); // doesn't erase
    }
    stuff.clear();
```

Comment: You are indeed allocating and freeing the memory correctly. But the question is why are you dynamically allocating them in the first place, instead of just `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It can be right, it's just not the best way.

Comment: Thanks! I just used *int as an example -- I use a class pointer in my vector

Comment: Doesn't make much difference, Pointers are rarely the right thing to use whether they point to classes or to integers.

Comment: If you want to store pointers in a vector, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<pointed_to_type>>`.

Comment: Should not it be `delete[] (stuff[i])` in the general case, in order to call the appropriate destructors for each element in the array (if needed) ?

Comment: You can use smart pointer and pass to constructor a callback to tell how you want to destroy your ressource.
But the conception is weird, if the stack don't allocate on push_back, it shouldn't free.
If you want to mix allocation and destruction in a vec, you probably want to extends its behavior.
I don'k know if u see what i mean.
GL !

Comment: @Damien: Absolutely not. The behaviour on using `delete[]` on a pointer created with `new` is undefined. Good sub-question though.

Comment: @Damien You only use `delete []` when you use `new []`.  The OP did not use `new []` so no `delete []`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 And ***I*** prefer not to call things wrong unless they are actually wrong! A wrong program is one with a bug in it. You can call them clunky, sub-optimal, etc... but unless you can actually prove that there is a bug here, they are not wrong.

Comment: @idclev463035818 "not right" means "wrong"

Comment: @user253751 Any decent code review based on modern C++ should flag owning raw pointers as an issue to investigate.

Comment: @user253751 you don't understand what I wanted to imply by putting it in "". If you insist that my statement was wrong, I'd rather remove the comment

Comment: `for (auto& p : stuff) { delete p; p = nullptr; }` if you are concerned about dangling pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a right way of deleting pointers in a vector?

Your code performs as you expect it to (and the memory is deleted correctly).

> Is it ok to use indices instead of itertors?

Yes.

That said, using iterators for accessing vector elements was added to the language to avoid indexing errors (which are some of the most common sources of bugs).

Since you are working with a vector of pointers (and I assume you access elements by index to avoid situations where you dereference an iterator into a pointer), consider iterating using `std::for_each` instead.

Comment: Thanks! How  `std::for_each` can be used in my example?

Comment: *"consider iterating using std::for_each instead"* Seems like a range-based for loop would be fine here.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a right way of deleting pointers in a vector? Yes. Is it ok to use indices instead of itertors? Yes.

By the time you enter the loop, the size of the vector is 3 and you will access the 3 elements you stored into it. For a short time, you will have dangling pointers, however, as you don't access them, that ain't a problem.

However, if I would encounter this in code review, I'd reject it.
If your statement would be to delete all instances, why not show you loop over all instances more clearly:

```
for (int *p : stuff)
    delete p;
```

Or even better, why don't you indicate that there is ownership?

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> stuff;
stuff.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(10));
stuff.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(20));
stuff.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(30));

stuff.clear();
```

This code is much shorter, it's also easier to maintain. As you can see, there ain't any explicit call to delete into it. However, it does happen as part of the clear.

Opposite your implied question, if I delete this pointer, how do I remove the iterator, this will automatically delete the pointer when you remove the iterator.